# pip.main() resetting logging settings in python

Tags: python, logging, pip

It seems that if I call `pip.main()` in my code my logging settings get reset.

Working example:

```
import logging
import pip

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug("Test")
# prints 'DEBUG:root:Test'

pip.main(["install", "requests"])
# prints pip output

logging.debug("Test")
# doesn't print anything
```

Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Comment: Why are you calling `pip.main` in your code? That is an extraordinarily strange thing to do.

Comment: My project includes a plugin manager which installs using pip.

Comment: It may not be acceptable functionality for `pip`, but it is what it is. IMO I've answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3043#issuecomment-237476013) in the [pip module](https://github.com/pypa/pip).

This is because when pip was created it was not intended to be imported into other programs, therefore considerations like changing root logging config were not thought about.

The work around suggested by the project maintainers is to use the `subprocess` module to call pip itself. They are open to pull requests to resolve this but it would require a large amount of work on the project.

Therefore my code now looks like

```
import logging
import subprocess

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug("Test")
# prints 'DEBUG:root:Test'

process = subprocess.Popen(["pip", "install", "requests"], 
                           shell=False,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
# prints pip output

logging.debug("Test")
# prints 'DEBUG:root:Test'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `install` command of `pip` overwrites the logging configuration. You need to reset the configuration yourself afterwards, e.g. by doing

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

again after the `pip.main()` call. Note that you may also have to add handlers, if the ones added by `pip` aren't what you want.

Comment: Thanks but this is not acceptable functionality for a module.

Comment: @JacobTomlinson It is *completely* appropriate for a function designed to be triggered be a command line tool instead of being called directly to set up logging.

Comment: @jpmc26 I agree with that, but the project maintainers have also agreed that in the situation where it is imported it shouldn't change the root logging